# Datapower_Remove All Null Elements Except One in SOAP to JSONX XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-datapower

I have a requirement where I am receiving SOAP Response in datapower which I am converting to JSONX, as the response is very big I am removing all the null elements using below code.But here I should not need to remove some elements even though I am getting null from backed. Could any one help please.

```
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="removenullfields" select="$response"/>
    <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="removenullfields" select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
    <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="*[not(self::elementname)][not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
```

Below is the sample response xml which I am getting from back end whcih I am converting to JSON, I would like to remove all the empty elements and objects
 which are coming from backed.I would like to send only these elements(allegation,coordinator-title,createUser-userId) even its coming empty from backend using generic logic as my xslt is very big 
 Can you please help me here.

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <Response>
      <Disp>
            <agency/>
            <allegation>Test</allegation>
            <test>
               <firstName>Test</firstName>
               <lastName>Test</lastName>
               <type>Test</type>
            </test>
            <coordinator>
               <userId></userId>
               <title>Test</title>
               <email></email>
            </coordinator>
            <Date>Test</Date>
            <User>
               <Id></Id>
               <clientName>0</clientName>
            </User>
             </Disp>
      </Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried below logic in json to soap conversion. It is working even when I pass empty value to the allegation field in the request.The same logic is not working for SOAP to JSON Transfrormation

```
  <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="*[not(self::allegation)][not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
```

Comment: can you please share sample xml?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a "null" element? You have one template that suggests it is a node which simply has no (non-empty) text nodes under it, but another template suggests you want to keep them if they have child nodes or attributes). Showing your input XML and expected output would help. Thanks!

Comment: @AmrendraKumar:

Comment: @AmrendraKumar and  Tim : I am sorry for late response as I was occupied with other things.Below is the sample response xml which I am getting from back end whcih I am converting to JSON, I would like to remove all the empty elements and objects which are coming from backed.I would like to send only these elements even its coming empty from backend using generic logic as my xslt is very big (<allegation>Test</allegation>, <coordinator><title>Test</title>   </coordinator>, <createUser><userId>Test</userId></createUser>. Can you please help me here.

Comment: <ns2:getProviderResponse>
   <Disputes>
            <agency/>
            <allegation>Test</allegation>
            <coordinator>
               <userId></userId>
               <title>Test</title>
               <email></email>
            </coordinator>
            <createDate>Test</createDate>
            <createUser>
               <userId></userId>
               <clientName>0</clientName>
            </createUser>
    </Disputes>
      </ns2:getProviderResponse>
@AmrendraKumar I couldnt able to past more than this size xml.

Comment: @TimC: Answering to your above comment NULL means if I get empty value from backend like <test></test>. I have pasted xml above, Can you please have a look.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I tried below logic in json to soap conversion. It is working even when I pass empty value to the allegation field in the request.The same logic is not working for SOAP to JSON Transfrormation                                       <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="*[not(self::allegation)][not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>

Comment: @TimC:  I tried below logic in json to soap conversion. It is working even when I pass empty value to the allegation field in the request.The same logic is not working for SOAP to JSON Transfrormation <xsl:template mode="removenullfields" match="*[not(self::allegation)][not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>

Comment: Can you please add all this information to the question itself, as code is very hard to read in comments. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC: I have updated in the question.